# Jetty: declare servlets in java in stead of web.xml when using maven

Tags: java, servlets, maven, jetty

Is it possible to use the embedded java code to add servlets:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
context.setContextPath("/");
server.setHandler(context);
context.getInitParams().put("useFileMappedBuffer", "false");
context.addServlet(new ServletHolder(new MyServlet()), "/myurl");
....
server.start();
server.join();
```

in stead of the lengthy web.xml way:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>package.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/myurl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I know this is posible in a non-maven project, but it seems the Maven Jetty plugin requires this web.xml method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Servlet 3.0](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315), servlets can be declared and mapped using the [`@WebServlet`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html) annotation. There is no configuration in the `web.xml` required, and no boilerplate Java code.

```
@WebServlet("/myurl")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet { ... }
```

However, the current release of [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/about.php) (7.x) only supports Servlet 2.5. Jetty 8.x is currently in development and supports Servlet 3.0. Unless you can use Jetty 8.x, or another servlet container that supports Servlet 3.0, you may need to continue using the web deployment descriptor for defining and mapping servlets.

I believe the [maven-jetty-plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin) currently only supports Jetty 7 and therefore may require the web.xml as you've found. You might check to see if there is a snapshot of the maven-jetty-plugin available that uses the experimental Jetty 8.x.

Comment: can't wait for a stable version of maven+jetty+servlet 3.0!

Answer (score 3):

In servlet 3.0 - yes, regardless of maven and jetty:

- Use [`ServletContext.addServlet(..)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29) where you specify the servlet name, and its class/instance/class name (3 overloaded methods)
- Then call `addMapping(..)` on the returned `ServletRegistration` to map it to url-pattern(s)